# Disable a text area by it's class (not id)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 2 text area's that are generated automatically, and I need to use JavaScript to disable both when the page has loaded. The catch is because they are generated automatically I can't give them an ID because they would both have the ID - *a big no*.

Attempted Javascript:

```
document.getElementByClassName('option_window-size').disabled=true;
```

I know this works because if I change *getElementbyClassName* to ID then it will work if I give the text areas the ID as well. But as I say it needs to work off class. Also it can't work of the Name attribute because that is automatically generated per product and per page...

I have tried this but it just doesn't work and I can't figure out why not because it should as the only thing I have changed is from ID to CLASS

Text Areas

```
<textarea name="willbeautogenerated" class="option_window-size" cols="40" rows="5">willbeautogenerated</textarea>
```

Additional note: I have tried to count and assign them different IDs using PHP but it gets far to complex. Also it is only these two that need disabling, thus I can't just disable all text area's on the page.

Comment: Would you mind using jQuery to make your life way easier?

Comment: getElementSSSSSByClassName returns a set of elements !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery makes this pretty simple:

```
$(".selector").prop("disabled", true);
```

**ALTHOUGH**!  It should be noted that this note appears on the man pages for `$.prop()` and `$.attr()`:

> Note: Attempting to change the type property (or attribute) of an input element created via HTML or already in an HTML document will result in an error being thrown by Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

This doesn't apply directly to your question, but you are changing `prop`/`attr`s on an input element, so be aware.

But it's still possible with plain old JS:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("selector"); // note: Elements, not Element

for(var e = 0; e < els.length; e++)
{
    els[e].disabled = true;
}
```

getElementsByClassName returns an NodeList, you just have to iterate over each element within.

Comment: Just want to point out that a _NodeList_ does not inherit from _Array_; you will get no methods from _Array.prototye_.

Comment: I had no idea (short of your answer below).  Edits made!

Answer (score 8):

> I know this works because if I change getElementByClassName to ID then it will work if I give the text areas the ID as well. But as I say it needs to work off class.

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a *NodeList* rather than a *Node* itself. You'll have to loop over the list, or if you expect just `1` item, choose index `0`.

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("option_window-size"),
    i = 0, e;

while (e = nodes[i++]) e.disabled = true;
```

Comment: In retrospect I should have just asked you to make this edit, but the 'B' in 'By' needs to be capital.  I added an example of the loop in my edit because edits need to be 6 characters long.  I just realized I copied the loop from my answer and that looks silly.  If the edit goes through feel free to just delete the loop.

Comment: @SandyGifford thanks for pointing it out, I'm surprised you added the same code as your answer and the edit got accepted; I've edited it again to change it to an alternative way :)

Comment: @SandyGifford it arose from my copy/pasting from quote, and I only noticed the missing _s_. I just noticed you edited the quote, too, which still won't work because the _s_ wasn't also added (because it's a quote).

Comment: HA, and we all fall down

Answer (score 1):

You can use class selector,

```
$('.option_window').attr('disabled', true);
```

OR

```
$('.option_window')[0].disabled = true;
```

Comment: I don't think they are using jQuery

Comment: @Coding It's one of the tags on the question

Comment: There question has jQuery tag

Comment: @SandyGifford Spot on it is one of my tags and have no issue with Jquery so I will give that ago. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery you can do:

```
//make sure to use .prop() and not .attr() when setting properties of an element
$('.option_window').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable textarea using jQuery:

```
$('.option_window-size').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

your missing a s in elements and the index where the element is like [0], for the first element.

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('option_window-size')[0].disabled=true;
```

or

```
  document.getElementsByName('willbeautogenerated')[0].disabled=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabel texarea using **.prop()** methode in jquery...

```
      $('.option_window-size').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

```
.option_window-size{display:none;}
```